# PhpStorm CodeIgniter 404 page not found

Tags: codeigniter

I am facing a problem with CodeIgniter framework in PhpStorm.

I have created a controller as `home.php` with a public function `test`. And I've created a view page as `mytest`.

In browser when I type `http://localhost/mvc/index.php/home/test/`
the page is not loading it shows

> "404 page not found".

What might be the problem?

Using XAMPP and CodeIgniter 2.1.0

Comment: Where is PhpStorm involved?

Comment: 404 page not found

Comment: Codeigniter 2 is done, its not getting updates any longer. Use Codeigniter 3, and work through the tutorial first http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/tutorial/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Check your class name,class name should be same as file name,which version of ci are you using?

Answer (score 0):

**Controller name** : Home.php

**Method / Function** : test()

**View** : mytest.php

```
class Home extends CI_Controller 
{ 
     public function test() 
     {
       $this->load->view('mytest');
     }
}
```